# How to model IC's enable (EN) pin in SPICE

Tags: integrated-circuit, spice

What is the best way to model an enable pin of an IC (SIP32508)? There is no schematic in the datasheet apart from the block diagram. I know that the pin can be driven between 0 and 5.5V and has the input leakage of 1 uA.

Comment: What IC is this? Digital? Analog? Does enable act as a clock enable, an output enable, a strobe, or some different control signal altogether?

Comment: The question is updated with device name.

Comment: And what does the rest of your model look like? Is it schematic? Behavioral? Something else? What modes of operation and faults do you need to handle in your simulation? I can't come up with anything more specific than "if EN is disabled, then turn off the main FET"

Comment: You still need to be more specific.  "Best" way can mean a bunch of things.  Do you need to know just how your driving circuitry gets affected by the Enable input parasitics?  Or do you need to model how the Enable signal propagates through the part and influences the delay time and slew rate characteristics of the FET driver?